# Is it still possible to download Visual C# Express 2005?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005

I have Visual C# Express installed on my PC (for XNA development back when that was required) and I can't uninstall it (it can't find one of the .msi files).  I'd like to reinstall it so I can then remove it but I can't find the installer.

Any idea where I can re-download the VC# Express 2005 installer?  I've looked all over Microsoft's web site but everything points back to the 2008 versions.  I've found some installers online but the sites are dubious freeware sites.

Comment: Why not upgrade to VC# 2008 ?

Comment: @Sathya: The point is Dana is trying to uninstall VS2005, but due to the missing .msi, has to reinstall/repair to do so.

Comment: I had the same problem : if he upgrades to VS2008 he will just compound the problem, because the 2 installations will get mixed-up. He HAS to get rid off 2005 BEFORE installing 2008. Else he will just double his problem.

Comment: @harrymc - 2008 can be installed alongside 2005 without any problems. They install into separate directories etc.

Comment: I've run both 2005 and 2008 before with no problems.  I'm just cleaning up and want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780741/where-is-visual-studio-2005-express-at/780822#780822

The direct download link is 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=51411&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, and it was a royal pain in the somewhere to totally remove VS2005.
The installation CD doesn't help, since your installation is already screwed up.
I finally found this article that made it possible : [How to remove Visual Studio 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907965).

Good luck.

Comment: That article may or may not work for the express edition, unless that's what you had.

Comment: I didn't have express, but this article was also given on the Microsoft site as the solution for express.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to MSDN (through school, work, or a personal account), you should be able to download it again. I know I can get VS2005 Express Editions through MSDNAA.